# AnkhSVN Client Side Ignore

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, ankhsvn

I have a SVN source controlled project which contains some generation scripts that require changes so they apply to the particular machine. However, I don't want to ever check these files back in. Is there some sort of client side ignore mechanism available in the AnkhSVN client that will prevent me from accidentally checking in these changes?

Comment: I do this via TortoiseSVN, right-click and add to ignore list. It will then not show up in the list of changes window upon check in. You may be able to do this within AnkhSVN via Subversion properties... with `svn:ignore`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using some different terms and finally ran across this article:

http://agilemusings.blogspot.com/2008/12/tortoisesvn-ignore-on-commit.html

Adding files to the ignore-on-commit changelist affects all clients so regardless of how you make this change it will apply to both Tortoise and AnkhSVN. Also, this doesn't have any effects on the repo itself so you won't be stepping on any toes if someone else on the project does need to make alterations to these files.

Answer (score 1):

I usually recommend to not-check in these files that are changed locally. You can create a template file instead. You can then customize the buildscript to copy the file in the right place if it is not already there.

Then you can just the `svn:ignore` setting (Right click Subversion->Ignore->... on an unversioned file), to make sure the file is not accidentally added.

Comment: Ohhh I really like this. I've heard lots of people recommending not to check these files in but that's usually where the advice ends. Adding a template instead is very clever.